# Clion: Error in debug but not in release mode

Tags: c++, debugging, release, clion

my problem is that if I compile my project with "Debug" configuration in CLion it returns this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/parallel/tags.h: In member function ‘__gnu_parallel::_ThreadIndex __gnu_parallel::parallel_tag::__get_num_threads()’:
/usr/include/c++/6/parallel/tags.h:66:38: error: ‘omp_get_max_threads’ was not declared in this scope
           return omp_get_max_threads();
```

But if I run the same code with "Release" configuration it works normal. Does somebody knows how to fix this error or why I can run it only by using the release configuration?

Comment: And you include the `<omp.h>` header file? And build with the `-fopenmp` flag?

Comment: As for the run configuration - check configuration settings in Run | Edit configurations. Which CLion version is it?

Comment: what should I check there... it is v 1.2.2